# Why does double list (my argument) not agree with Parse Line/Map function in main? F#

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

Okay so I have came down to one last thing which it causes error in the main according to Visual Studio, "This type was expected to have type `double list` , but here has `double` type." I will show you the codes with error. I have this average function to compute the values and it was declared as double list. Why does it complain in the main? I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, but it's pretty hard for me to explain why. **FORGOT One more thing** - I was trying to read the text file with my program.

```
let avg (values:double list) =
    let rec sum values accum =
        match values with
        |  [] -> accum
        |  head :: tail -> sum tail (accum + head/12.0)
    sum values 0.0

let ReadFile filename =
  [ for line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename) -> line ]

let ParseLine (line:string) =
  let strings = line.Split('\t')
  let strlist = Array.toList(strings)
  let year = System.Int32.Parse(strlist.Head)
  let values = List.map System.Double.Parse strlist.Tail
  (year, avg values)
```

in the main

```
let result = file |> List.map(fun el -> 
    let (year, values) = ParseLine el 
    (year, avg values)) //values gets the error as described above.

  result |> List.iter(fun (year, avgRainfall) -> printfn "%i: %f" year avgRainfall)
```

Comment: That error message is almost certainly incorrect - there is no such type as `double float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was answered in a previous question but here it is because `let result = ... (year, avg values)`. `ParseLine` is already calculating the avg so it is no longer a list but just a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with @Gary.S's help, I came across this.

```
let avg (values:double list) =
    let rec sum values accum =
        match values with
        |  [] -> accum
        |  head :: tail -> sum tail (accum + head/12.0)
    sum values 0.0

let ReadFile filename =
  [ for line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename) -> line ]

let ParseLine (line:string) =
  let strings = line.Split('\t')
  let strlist = Array.toList(strings)
  let year = System.Int32.Parse(strlist.Head)
  let values = List.map System.Double.Parse strlist.Tail
  (year, values) // Removed Avg.
```

in the main

```
  let result = file |> List.map(fun el -> 
    let (year, values) = ParseLine el 
    (year, avg values)) // it works!!!

  result |> List.iter(fun (year, avgRainfall) -> printfn "%A: %A" year avgRainfall)
```